# Skip multiple iterations in a loop

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, list, iteration

Looking for something that would allow skipping multiple `for` loops while also having current `index` available.

In pseudo code, is would look something like this:

```
z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
for element in z:
     <calculations that need index>
    skip(3 iterations) if element == 5
```

Is there such a thing in Python 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd iterate over `iter(z)`, using `islice` to send unwanted elements into oblivion... ex;

```
from itertools import islice
z = iter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

for el in z:
    print(el)
    if el == 4:
        _ = list(islice(z, 3))  # Skip the next 3 iterations.

# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 8
```

**Optimization**
If you're skipping *maaaaaaany* iterations, then at that point `list`ifying the result will become memory inefficient. Try iteratively consuming `z`:

```
for el in z:
    print(el)
    if el == 4:
        for _ in xrange(3):  # Skip the next 3 iterations.
            next(z)
```

Thanks to @Netwave for the suggestion.

---

If you want the index too, consider wrapping `iter` around an `enumerate(z)` call (for python2.7.... for python-3.x, the `iter` is not needed).

```
z = iter(enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]))
for (idx, el) in z:
    print(el)
    if el == 4:
        _ = list(islice(z, 3))  # Skip the next 3 iterations.

# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 8
```

Comment: generating a "trash" list doesnt look the best option I think. Maybe consume it wih a simple loop? `for _ in xrange(3): next(z)`, btw, no need to use `iter`, because `islice` behaves like an iterator already

Comment: I like this answer, but would reverse the order. `next` first, `list(islice(...))` as an educational alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `while` loop for this purpose.

```
z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
i = 0

while i < len(z):
    # ... calculations that need index
    if i == 5:
        i += 3
        continue

    i += 1
```

Comment: This doesn't actually skip loop iterations.

Comment: Okay, that looks good. Btw, I did not downvote you, but I hope the downvoter sees this and reverses it.

Comment: Hmm, one more suggestion, you may end up skipping an extra iteration by mistake, so take a look at that again.